# Lists in spoiler tag

Tags: bug, support, formatting

When quoting, lists work fine. For instance

```
> A list of
>
>  * one, nay
>  * two
> items
```

becomes

> A list of
>
> - one, nay
> - two
>     items

But if I do the same with the spoiler tag it fails, namely

```
>! A list of
>!
>!  * one, nay
>!  * two
>! items
```

becomes

> A list of
>
>   * one, nay
>   * two
>  items

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Reported on the main meta: [Markdown not appropriately rendering unordered list spoilers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129441)

Answer (score 1):

Spoiler markup doesn't interact well with other markup. I believe this is in part by design: you shouldn't put too much content under spoiler markup. For example, it is deliberate that you can't put two consecutive paragraphs in spoiler markup.

Comment: If this is by design, it is a bad design (imho).

Comment: "By design" seems to imply that it is *intentionally* broken this way.  While the design as-is may lend itself towards breaks like this, I doubt it was intentional.

Comment: @Iszi I don't know if this particular case (lists in spoilers) is intentionally broken, but it is intentional that little effort is spent to make X in spoilers work.